# Formattable does not render output in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, htmlwidgets

The code works normally in Rstudio, the code is

```
library(datatable)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

datatable(report) %>% formatStyle('status',target = 'row',
            backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("Completed","Over run"), c('lightgreen','red')))
```

However, I don't know how to output this datatable/formattable? in Shiny.

The error says:

```
no applicable method for 'as.htmlwidget' applied to an object of class "c('datatables', 'htmlwidget')"
```

Comment: Where does the error come from. Please add a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

I hopte this litte shinyApp will help you. Since I dont have your dataframe `report`, I replaced it by the `iris` dataframe. So the `formatStyle` will look for the column `Species` and color them differently.

In the ui you define the output via `DT::dataTableOutput("YourTableID")` and in the server you define an output like `output$YourTableID <- DT::renderDataTable({ ... })`, in which you place the code to generate a datatable.

Also the library you are looking for is `DT` not `datatable`.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

report <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(report) %>% formatStyle('Species',target = 'row',
                                      backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("setosa","versicolor", "virginica"), 
                                                                   c('lightgreen','red', "yellow")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```